# Is there a dictionary like collection that can use a property of its value as the key?

Tags: .net, collections, dictionary

Instead of using `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` I want some type of collection class that can use a property of the value as the key, is there something like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is - [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx).

That's abstract, and there are no concrete derived classes in the framework as far as I can see, but all you need to implement is `GetKeyForItem` as far as I can see. For example, you could do this with a delegate:

```
public class DelegatingKeyedCollection<TKey, TItem> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>
{
    private readonly Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector;

    public DelegatingKeyedCollection(Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        this.keySelector = keySelector;
    }

    protected override TKey GetKeyForItem(TItem item)
    {
        return keySelector(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

KeyedCollection as Jon Skeet says is the obvious candidate.

A few random remarks about this class:

- You will of course want the property that you use as the key to be readonly.
- Its method `Contains(TItem item)` is inherited from `Collection<T>`, and is implemented by iterating through the collection.  This can therefore be much slower than `Contains(TKey key)`.  It's too easy for developers to make the mistake of using the wrong overload, so it may be worth considering implementing your own `Contains(TItem item)` method:

  ```
  public new bool Contains(TItem item)
  {
      if (item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
      return this.Contains(GetKeyForItem(item));
  }
  ```
- Unlike an IDictionary, it doesn't have a method `TryGetValue`.  This can be useful and it might be worth implementing your own:

  ```
  public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TItem item)
  {
      // If the dictionary exists, use it
      if (Dictionary != null) return Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out item);
      // Else do it the hard way
      if (!this.Contains(key))
      {
          item = default(TItem);
          return false;
      }
      item = this[key];
      return true;
  }
  ```
- It doesn't support enumeration of the keys, which can be useful:

  ```
  public IEnumerable<TKey> GetKeys()
  {
      foreach (TItem item in this)
      {
          yield return GetKeyForItem(item);
      }
  }
  ```
- Serialization can be inefficient, as it will serialize both its internal list and its internal dictionary.  You can get round this if you need to by implementing custom serialization.

Comment: +1, that's how keyed collection should have been implemented. Two suggestions, I would call it `TryGetItem` and make `GetKeys` a property like `Keys`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a normal one, and when you set the key value pair, specify the property of the value you are interested in.

That was too easy, I must be misunderstanding your request.

Maybe you wanted to use an arbitrary property later rather than at input time.  In that case, I think you would have to use multiple dictionary objects (perhaps tied together in a helper class).

Comment: If you set the property of the object after you add it, it will be out of sync with the key in the collection.