# .Net data structure that combines set and dictionary semantics

Tags: .net, collections, dictionary, set

Is there an out-of-the-box generic collection type for .Net that combines Set and Dictionary semantics, such that I only store items, but can also do fast look-ups by some key that is derived from each item? Something like this:

```
var foos = new KeyedSet<string, Foo>(foo => foo.ID);

foos.Add(new Foo { ID = "X234", Descr = "One foo" });
foos.Add(new Foo { ID = "Q909", Descr = "Another foo" });

Console.WriteLine("Foo Q909 is {0}", foos["Q909"].Descr);
```

Comment: How does this differ from a dictionary that is used with <Foo.ID, Foo>?

Comment: @Joe: A Dictionary would require `foos.Add("X234", new Foo { ID = "X234", Descr = "One foo" });`, which is redundant, tedious and error-prone. I could write a helper method, but then I'd have to remember to use it all the time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a dictionary like collection that can use a property of its value as the key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773950/is-there-a-dictionary-like-collection-that-can-use-a-property-of-its-value-as-th)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx)

Comment: Perfect! I hadn't heard of the `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace. Thank you very much.